# Is below undestanding on pushstate/popstate correct in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I have successfully integrated pushstate and popstate, navigating back and forward in the browser and it works perfectly, but! it all dies if you do a refresh of the page.

Say you are on the main page, you navigate to page a.html and then to page b.html and finallay c.html
If you now go back to b.html (all successful popstate events so far) and now click the refresh button in your browser, and try to either go back in history to page a.html or forward to page c.html absolutely nothing happens. Doesn't this render the whole thing useless? 
How can I possibly convince my client to want this on his website if I have to tell him it doesn't support his users refreshing any page....

Please tell me I'm wrong and tell me what I might be doing wrong or have missed. I guess it makes sense it should lose it though, as a refresh is a new GET request...but it doesn't even fire a new GET request in the above example after! the refresh, it just doesn't do **anything**.
Test in Vivaldi, Chrome, and Firefox.

Comment: [Check out this document on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API) The very last section describes the issue you are experiencing. Hopefully it helps you.

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren Thank you, I got it to work. If you post your comment as an answer instead I will set it as the accepted.

Comment: No that's fine, I don't think an answer that just links to an external website is justified as an answer. I am happy to hear you got it to work in the end.